# favicon internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, favicon, internal-server-error

I changed win for ios and now I can't open the admin of a website I've created.

The error is:

> Request URL:http://local.mysite/favicon.ico
>
> Request Method:GET Status Code:500
>
> Internal Server Error
>
> Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80

I have tried looking at xampp/logs and no error is shown.

I've tried adding:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
  RedirectMatch 403 favicon.ico
</IfModule>
```

to the .htaccess file

also added to the code: `<link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">`

but I'm going blind on this, don't know what else to do.

this is `my .htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: does `favicon.ico` exist?

Comment: I have a favicon.png instead

Comment: do you have other redirects in your htaccess?

Comment: @WEBjuju please take a look at my edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that previously since favicon.ico existed, you didn't notice this.  When you removed it, the "file doesn't exist, so go to index.php" started the behavior.  Try putting this in the top of your index.php:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/favicon.ico') exit('');
```

or beef it up by sending something with the appropriate headers or even output that png (with the appropriate header for png).

**OR**

how about just putting a favicon back, it can be that same png, but then you're not battling this issue any more.

Comment: not working, sorry... the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] doesn't have favicon

Comment: can you determine that the 500 error is being issued by the index.php or not?

Comment: well I'm using codeigniter, so my index.php file has some configs. The error just says what I wrote

Comment: how about just putting a favicon back, it can be that same png, but then you're not battling this issue any more.