# Why do I keep getting a 500(Internal Server Error) GET http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico 500 (Internal Server Error)?

Tags: reactjs, express, create-react-app

When I began this project I didn't keep anything from the CRA files that are generated, so why do I still get this error, where is it comming from?

```
GET http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

As I said, I have created my own ./public/index.html in which I am not specifying a favicon.
What is the source of this error and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [favicon internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292220/favicon-internal-server-error)

Comment: I added an empty link for favicon and i doesn't work.
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I said, I have created my own ./public/index.html in which I am not specifying a favicon. What is the source of this error and how can I get rid of it?

Browsers automatically request the favicon. If no favicon is specified in the html file an automatic request is made to `<protocol>://<domain>/favicon.ico`

> I added an empty link for favicon and i doesn't work. `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">`

The browser still sees an empty href as a favicon that has not been specified in the html file.

You can set your own favicon url via the href in `<link rel="shortcut icon">` and serve an .ico file or just ignore the requests.
At this time I'm not aware of a way to disable the favicon requests entirely.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue. I had the following in the `<head>`.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
```

The icon file was in the root of `/app` but I also noticed I had another copy in the `/public` folder. After deleting the one in `/public`, the issue was resolved.